# Select name file then go to other lines?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/ch6v8jrd/) I want when the user clicks on "OK" first open browser file after user select file then continue other line. But my program before I select file go to other line. How can I do this?

```js
popFileSelector = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
    if (el) {
        el.click();  
    }
};

window.popWithDelay = function() {
        popFileSelector();
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '1!<br />';
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '2!<br />';
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '3!<br />';
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '4!<br />';

    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '5!<br />';
  
    
};
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
      <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" />
  </form>
     <br />
  <a href="javascript:popWithDelay()">OK</a>
    <div id="log">Log: <br /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Henry, welcome to SO. Your question is still vague. What do you mean with other line. Could you try to be as specific as possible what you are looking for. And what efforts have you tried already?

Comment: You can't, you will have to wait for a selection, so you need to break code up into parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code ensures that the other lines are only printed if the `input` actually changes.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/am6f8e0w/).

```js
window.popFileSelector = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
  if (el) {
    el.click();
  }
};

window.popWithDelay = function(event) {
  handleFiles(event.target.files);

  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '1!<br />';
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '2!<br />';
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '3!<br />';
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '4!<br />';

  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '5!<br />';
}

window.handleFiles = function(files) {
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += 'This is the handleFiles() function<br />';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="popWithDelay(event)" />
  </form>
  <br />
  <a href="javascript:popFileSelector()">Pop With 1 Second Delay</a>
  <div id="log">Log: <br /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @henrry That's because the `handleFiles()` function doesn't exist. Add it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use callback function

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sedatnz/2/)

```
popFileSelector = function(callback) {
    var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
    if (el) {
        el.click(); 
        el.addEventListener('change', callback);
    }
};


window.popWithDelay = function() {
    var func = function() {
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '1!<br />';
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '2!<br />';
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '3!<br />';
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '4!<br />';
      document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += '5!<br />';
    }

    popFileSelector(func);
};
```

Comment: when i click on 'Pop With 1 Second Delay' any click  function run 1 more. my means  if i 5 time click on  'Pop With 1 Second Delay' that 1+2+3+4+5 time  run. how can i fix this?